# How To Fix Google App Script error Exception: Data storage error (line 1, file "Code")?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, exception

I have Google App Script Project it ran well but now suddenly when I try to refresh it, it shows an error `Exception: Data storage error (line 1, file "Code")`. I checked my other projects and it shows the same. Do you know how to fix it?

[image: Here's the screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out that it's an error from the Google. My first code line is a Property Service. Someone posted the issue. But now it works as usual.
Here's the posted issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162647522